# Simple Stored Procedures are slower than standard queries! why?

Tags: php, stored-procedures, benchmarking

One of benefits of Stored Procedures is good speed. I ran some tests and got some strange results!

Scenario: There are 2 InnoDB tables, Agents and Companies. Each agent is related to ONE company via FK and indexed are correct.
Please look at ways below:

Two simple queries:

```php
$agent = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM agents WHERE id=3")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$company = $pdo->query("SELECT name FROM companies WHERE id='$agent[company]'")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$name = $company['name'];
// 0.000793933868408
// 0.000741958618164
```

One query with JOIN

```php
$agent = $pdo->query("
    SELECT agents.*, companies.name FROM agents
    LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id=agents.company
    WHERE agents.id=3
")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$name = $agent['name'];
// 0.000327110290527
// 0.00028395652771
```

Two SP calls:

```php
$agent = $pdo->query("CALL agents('3')")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$partner = $pdo->query("CALL companies('$agent[company]')")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$name = $agent['name'];
// 0.010176897049
// 0.010200023651

/*
CREATE PROCEDURE `agents`(agent INT(10))
BEGIN SELECT * FROM agents WHERE id=agent; END

CREATE PROCEDURE `companies`(company INT(10))
BEGIN SELECT * FROM companies WHERE id=company; END
*/
```

One SP call with JOIN:

```php
$agent = $pdo->query("CALL agents('3')")->fetch();
$name = $agent['name'];
// 0.00241208076477
// 0.00252604484558

/*
CREATE PROCEDURE `agents`(agent INT(10))
BEGIN
    SELECT agents.*, companies.name FROM agents
    LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id=agents.company
    WHERE agents.id=agent;
END
*/
```

How these simple SPs are slow as you saw? May PDO or system environment cause it?
As i know SPs works great for simple queries but here.....

Please note that times above have been recored after 3 times running.

Thanks
AHHP

Answer (score 3):

First: queries are cached. Running them more than once will mainly show you how fast MySQL can retrieve their previous result from the cache. You can prevent this (a bit) by added `SQL_NO_CACHE` after your `SElECT` keyword.

Then, stored procedures are only as fast as the code they execute. If you execute a query inside a stored procedure, it will never be faster than just the query. It is still the same query, but with some additional overhead of running the stored procedure.

It can seem faster, if you don't return data from the stored procedure. The result of the executed query is sent to the caller. If you don't do that in the stored procedure, the speed you gain, is simply because of sending less data.

Then, the queries you execute in the stored procedure isn't the same as the separate query. In the separate query, you enter the exact value in the query string before it is sent to MySQL, while in the stored procedure, you actually have a parameterized query where you padd the value as a parameter to the mysql engine (although this fact is hidden a little bit by the syntax of calling queries in a stored proc. This means that calling these procedure for the first time, causes MySQL to have to parse that query again, while the 'constant value' version is already cached.

So in conclusion, your test is wrong.

A stored procedure *is* faster if you need to do some processing or filtering that cannot be done in a single query. Fetching all data to PHP and processing it there, causes too much data to be send back and forth between PHP and MySQL. If you do all the processing in a stored procedure, and only send the (small) result, this is faster, but mainly because all processing stays inside the SQL engine, so there's no serialization/deserialization nor sending back and forth of data.

Comment: Thanks @GolezTrol for detailed reply. About caching, i ran queries several times and result are for last tests so quereis had to be cached. About 2nd paragraph, as i found out, SP makes queries fast only via caching? About 3rd paragraph, would you explain me more? Using SPs as processor (not to return data, just do something) makes them a bit useless! I didnt understand your meaning. And about last paragraph, my test is not benchmark. In my test i have a variable and want to get a field from its relation. Im looking for doing such tasks in the best way not to discuss about MySQL testing

Comment: The third paragraph refers to what I say in the last. You can use stored procedures to process data and return that. In your case, you just execute the query, return its result, and that's it. So the stored procedure should be able to run in at a minimum the time it takes to execute the procedure, because it does exactly that, plus a little overhead of calling the procedure itself. If wrapping a query like this in a stored procedure would make it faster, everyone would be doing it. Or more likely, it would be done automatically by MySQL. :)